# PHP - Sort mysql_fetch_array based on number

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a tabel with 10 Rows in it,

They look like this :

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ ID + ACTIVE + NAME + DESCRIPTION    +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  + 1      + ONE  + O-N-E          +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2  + 2      + TWO  + T-W-O          +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 3  + 0      + THREE+ T-H-R-E-E      +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 4  + 4      + FOUR + F-O-U-R        +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 5  + 5      + FIVE + F-I-V-E        +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 6  + 3      + SIX  + S-I-X          +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I'm getting the values of this table by using

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ACTIVE != 0") or die (mysql_error());
```

And then I'm fetching them with :

```
$values = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error());
```

But now the problem is, that the come out this way :
1
2
4
5
3

And I would like to order this while keeping the NAME and DESCRIPTION that belong to the ACTIVE .

I've read a little bit about sorting 2D array's but I'm not getting anywhere, so if anyone has a clear solution or clear article that would help me alot!
Thanks for reading.

Comment: You are better off sorting them at the database level, see `ORDER BY`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Thanks, is changing mysql to mysqli functions only a case of an extra letter or do I need to change alot more in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, switch to `mysqli` or whatever, but the answer to your question is: Add `ORDER BY ID` to your query:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ACTIVE != 0 ORDER BY ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use

```
while ($values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo $values['NAME']." ".$values['DESCRIPTION'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_fetch_assoc and access your values by using $values['nameOfValue']

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) directly in mysql?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ACTIVE != 0 ORDER BY ACTIVE ASC") or die (mysql_error());
```

Then I would like you to remember that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)